# How to open specific html in one frame from being in another frame?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, frame, frameset

I have a frames in frameset as follow :

```
<frameset rows="75%,25%">
    <frameset cols="20%,80%">
        <frame src="TreeGroup.jsp" name="left" id="f1"/>
        <frame src="DisplayMap.jsp"   name="top" id="f2"/>
    </frameset>
    <frame src="Tabs.jsp" name="bottom"/>
</frameset>
```

in frame `f1` I have `context menu` options so If I click `AddVehicle` option in frame `f1` it should open new jsp/html in frame2 (`f2`). So in Javascript function I did like this,

```
 function addVehicle()
 {
   alert("In addVehicle");
//parent.top.location.href="http://localhost:8080/ITS_Server/Vehicle_Registration.jsp";
   top.frames['top'].location.href = "http://localhost:8080/ITS_Server/Vehicle_Registration.jsp?gname="+grp_name+"&did="+'<%=uid%>', "toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=100,bottom=200, left=200, width=900, height=500";

 }
```

Here The problem I am facing is , `top.frames['top'].location.href` is working fine only if I remove all the parameters to URL and also it is not open in `f2` frame it opens in a full window. How to solve this can anyone help me inthis please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to set the source of frame f2 instead of setting the location.href property.
something like follows:

```
var frmap = document.getElementById("f2");
frmap.src = "new url";
```

Comment: its an error telling that `cannot set property src of null`

Comment: I am trying to call another page from `TreeGroup.jsp` and here id `f2` is in another file which has the code only I mensioned above , So how can `gwtElementById()` work in `TreeGroup.jsp` page

Comment: Just give this a try:top.window.frames["f2"]

Comment: I am not very sure of the syntax, but you need to access frame f2 using dom hierarchy, you can also give a try to self.parent.document.getElementbyId("f2"). Just check the hierarchy using some debugging tools, (in .net we can check using watch window) and try to use the same.